# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(routeConfigs)') React native Project app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So i'm currently developing a react native application, but i'm getting this error. I think it may have to do with the version of some libraries that i'm using but i'm not sure.

This is my app.js file

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import MapScreen from './screens/MapScreen';
import { store } from './store';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";

export default function App() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
            name='HomeScreen'
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
            name='MapScreen'
            component={MapScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

My HomeScreen.js file, which is rendered when the app starts.

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Image } from 'react-native'
import tw from 'tailwind-react-native-classnames';
import NavOptions from '../components/NavOptions';

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style = {tw`bg-white h-full`}>
            <View style = {tw`p-5`}>
                <Image
                style = {{
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    resizeMode: "contain",
                }}
                source={{
                    uri: "https://links.papareact.com/gzs"
                }} 
                />
                <NavOptions/>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

My MapScreen.js file, the other screen I have.

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

const MapScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Here is the map stuff...</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default MapScreen
```

The NavOptions.js file, which renders two buttons on the screen to select one.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React from 'react'
import { FlatList, Text, Touchable, TouchableOpacity, View, Image } from 'react-native'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements/dist/icons/Icon';
import tw from 'tailwind-react-native-classnames';

const data = [
    {
        id: "123",
        title: "Get a ride",
        image: "https://links.papareact.com/3pn",
        screen: "MapScreen",
    },
    {
        id:"456",
        title:"Order food",
        image: "https://links.papareact.com/28w",
        screen: "EatsScreen", // Change in future....
    }
]

const NavOptions = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return (
        <FlatList 
        data = {data} 
        horizontal
        keyExtractor = {(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate(item.screen)}
                style = {tw`p-2 pl-6 pb-8 pt-4 bg-gray-200 m-2 w-40`}
            >
                <View>
                    <Image
                    style = {{
                        width: 120,
                        height: 120,
                        resizeMode: "contain",
                    }}
                    source={{
                        uri: item.image
                    }} 
                    />
                    <Text style={tw`mt-2 text-lg font-semibold`}>{item.title}</Text>
                    <Icon 
                    style = {tw`p-2 bg-black rounded-full w-10 mt-4`}
                    name="arrowright" color="white" type="antdesign"/>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        />
    )
}

export default NavOptions
```

Comment: Please edit question to include all relevant code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

normally undefined is not a object occurs when you are asking for parameter value from parameter that does not exist.
for example:

```
let data = [
             {
             arr:[{name:"aaa"},{name:"bbb"}],
             b:'outside1'
             },
             {
             arr:[{name:"ccc"},{name:"ddd"}],
             b:'outside2'
             },
           ]
```

in here if you right data[0].b then it will return outside1
but data[0].b.c will be undefine and data[0].b.c.d will give error undefined is not a object.

in your code I am not seeing any this kind of pattern so please check your code if this is happening anywhere .

Comment: Yes, so i realized it had to do with the stack object in the app.js file

Answer (score 0):

For others with the same error but in different context: 
I had this issue when I imported modules from 'aws-amplify-react-native', but 'aws-amplfify-react-native' wasn't installed and so it was "undefined"